# File count within directories in unix using recursive approach

Tags: bash, function, recursion, count, hp-ux

Problem Statement: To list down the count of files within a directory. 
Note: A directory may either contain a sub-directory or files but not both. 
Need to list count of files directory wise.
Here is the piece of code.

```
#!/usr/bin/sh 
directory_navigate()
{   
    path=$1
    cd $path
    dir_count=`ls -l|grep '^d'|wc -l`
    if [ $dir_count -gt 0 ]
    then
        for dir in `ls`
        do
            sub_path="$path/$dir"
            directory_navigate $subpath
        done
    else    
        sub_path=`pwd`
        file_count $sub_path 
        return
    fi
}   

file_count ()
{
    path=$1
    cd $path
    count=`ls|wc -l`
    echo "Count of files in $path is $count"
    return
}

main()
{
    filepath=/var/prod/data/extract/tbill
    directory_navigate $filepath
    return 
}

main
```

This throws the following error: recursion too deep

Comment: What about just using `find`?

Answer (score 2):

Use `globstar` . In `bash` do

```
shopt -s globstar
count=0
for name in /basefolder/**
do
[ -f "$name" ] && (( count++ ))
done
echo "Total files : $count"
```

A simpler approach as suggested in the comment is

```
find /basefolder/ -type f -printfc | wc -c
```

Here, the catch is that we don't have to parse( and are not parsing, we just want to count) the files, if we require to parse the files for more complex requirements, then below are some reasons for not using find.

- Using find requires that you need to null-delimit each file (ie use `-print0`).
- Furthermore, you need to use `while - read -r -d ' '` combination to parse each file.
- In short, not worth the effort.

**Edit:** If you want to have a directory-wise file-count listing, do below

```
#!/bin/bash
shopt -s globstar
for name in ~/Documents/so/**
do
if [ -d "$name" ]
then
  count="$(find "$name" -type f -printf c | wc -c)"
  echo "Total files in $name : $count"
fi
done
```

Comment: As a side note, globstar is only available since bash 4.0. Some OS like MacOS won't have it by default and will need to upgrade their shell.

Comment: @Aserre : Good note, I am aware of this. The op mentioned `unix` in question, so hopefully he has bash version > 4.0

Comment: MacOS is Unix-based :)

Comment: How about using `find . -type f -printf c | wc -c`? Doesn't need a lot of effort

Comment: @user000001 : That won't deal with non-standard files like `AnewlineB`. In fact those files are rare but they do exists on some machines.

Comment: @sjsam: Yes it can handle it. It prints a single character for each file regardless of the filename. Of course there is the problem that some `find` implementations may not have the `printf` option...

Comment: @Aserre : Again i agree, but users on `Mac` generally tag `Mac` in the questions.

Comment: @user000001 : It won't. `find` unlike `ls` will not add random characters in place of newlines, indeed that is one speciality of `find`.

Comment: @sjsam: That sounds really strange. Post the output of `find . -type f -printf c` on your console. You should see the character `c` printed several times, regardless of the filenames contained inside the current directory

Comment: @user000001 : I am sorry, I  overlooked the `-printf c` in your comment. Yes it does what it is supposed to do..  :)

Comment: hi, the requirement here is to find the count of files directory wise. So find function doesn't fulfill this requirement and also printf option does not work